# Dynamically create TextView with listeners

Tags: android, database, textview, onclicklistener

Please don't be so strict, I never did this before.

I have database with some hobbies and their id.
What I need is dynamically create some quantity of TextView for every hobby. With this no problem :)

But then i need to set onClickListener on each of this textView, and if one of them was clicked - get id for this hobby from database.

Any ideas please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe `setTag(id)` with id of hobby and inside `OnClickListener` obtain this tag by `(int) v.getTag()`

Comment: thanks, i will try it in a few minutes :)
sorry for so simple question... and thanks for help :)